# How can I get the seprate results for each pattern from multiple grep

Tags: grep

I would like to search 14 different patterns within 100 files. 
At the moment what I tried

```
cat s_3_2_*_qseq.txt | grep  -c  'pattern1\|pattern2\|pattern3\|pattern4\|pattern5\|...pattern14'
```

This gives me the no of all pattern in each file

```
    s_3_3_001_qseq.txt:12
    s_3_3_002_qseq.txt:15
    .

    s_3_3_0068_qseq.txt:5
```

I am interested to see results for each pattern indivually as follwing:

```
file                  pattern1   pattern2   .....   pattern14
s_3_3_001_qseq.txt:    0         2                  5
s_3_3_002_qseq.txt:    7         1                  3
.
.
s_3_3_0068_qseq.txt:   1         2                  1
```

Any idea how can I do it, unix, perl or python solution would be nice.

Comment: Try without -c option to the grep. '-c' option is to count number of matches.

Comment: `-c` option counts the number of all occurrences of all patterns. You can not get the count of individual matches. To attain that result, you have to run `grep -c` with one pattern at a time, 14 times.

Comment: any other way to do it automatically instead of doing 14 times

Comment: I mean other the grep??

Comment: @TCFPHCDG Not with grep theres not.

Comment: Awk would do it.

Comment: could you please share how can I do it

Comment: CAT ABUSE - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-badunixhabits.html#ten

Answer (score 2):

Using Awk:

Provide search terms in a comma separated variable called search.

```
$ cat a
alice
bob
john

$ cat b
alice
bob

$ cat c
alice

$ cat search-count.awk
BEGIN {
    # read search terms
    split(search, searches, /,/)
    delim=":"

    # fill initially zero count for all searches
    for (f = 1; f < ARGC; f++)
        for (s in searches)
            matches[searches[s],delim,ARGV[f]] = 0
}

{
    for (s in searches) {
        if ($0 ~ searches[s]) {
            matches[searches[s],delim,FILENAME]++
        }
    }
}

END {
    # print header
    printf "FILE"
    for (s in searches) {
        printf "\t%s", searches[s]
    }
    printf "\n"

    # print counts
    for (f = 1; f < ARGC; f++) {
        printf ARGV[f]
        for (s in searches) {
            printf "\t%s", matches[searches[s],delim,ARGV[f]]
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
}


$ awk -v search="alice,bob,john" -f ./search-count.awk a b c
FILE    alice   bob     john
a       2       2       0
b       1       1       0
c       0       2       0
```

Answer (score 2):

An awk solution - code could be tidied up or shortened - I m sure

```
$ cat file1
pat1
pat2
pat1

$ cat file2
pat2
pat2
pat1

$ awk -f  1.awk file1 file2

file          pat1      pat2        
file1       2       1       
file2       1       2       

$ cat 1.awk
BEGIN{
  pat["pat1"]="pat1"; 
  pat["pat2"]="pat2"; 
  file["file1"]="file1"; 
  file["file2"]="file2"
} 

{
  for (i in pat) {
    if ($0 ~ i) pat_count[FILENAME,i]++ 
  } 
} 
END {
  printf("file\t\t")
  for(i in pat) {
    printf("%s\t\t",i)
  }
  printf("\n")

  for (i in file) {
    printf("%s\t\t",i) 
      for(j in pat) {
        printf("%d\t\t",  pat_count[i,j])
      } ; printf("\n") 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PATTERNS=(dummy pattern1 pattern2 ... pattern14) ; dummy to occupy index zero
for file in /path/to/my/files/*
do
  for p in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
  printf ${file}"\t"
  do
    c=$(grep -c PATTERNS[${p}] ${file}) # depending on the nature of your pattern you may need quotes around it
    printf ${c}"\t"
  done
  echo
done
```

something like this may work (not syntax checked, please use caution if you decide to use it)